# Strange characters when displaying the char array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, output, symbols

I can't correctly display information. In the text displayed extra characters. Most likely a problem with the zero character but I was not able to eliminate.

**First file: person.h** Here I describe a simple class.

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_INCLUDED
#define PERSON_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

using std::string;

class Person
{
private:
    static const int m_iLIMIT = 25;
    string m_sLname;         // lastname
    char m_cFname[m_iLIMIT];    // firstname
public:
    Person () { m_sLname = ""; m_cFname[0] = '\0'; }  // #1
    Person(const string & sLn, const char * pcFn = "Adam"); // #2

    // show lastname и firstname
    void Show() const;          // format: firstname lastname
    void FormalShow() const;    // format: lastname, firstname
};

#endif // PERSON_H_INCLUDED
```

**Second file: p_functions.cpp** Here I define class methods

```
#include "person.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

// #2
Person::Person(const string & sLn, const char * cFn)
{
    m_sLname = sLn;
    strcat(m_cFname, cFn);
}

void Person::Show() const
{
    cout << "First format: " << m_cFname << ", " << m_sLname << endl;
}

void Person::FormalShow() const
{
    cout << "Second format: " << m_sLname << ", " << m_cFname << endl;
}
```

**Third file: main.cpp** Here I am testing methods

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Person one;

    Person two("Smith");

    Person three("immanuel", "Kant");

    one.Show();
    one.FormalShow();

    two.Show();
    two.FormalShow();

    three.Show();
    three.FormalShow();


    return 0;
}
```

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaHnl.png) I get

Comment: Good reasons to learn how to use the debugger and step through your code line by line.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Informative answer.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem, but is there any particular reason why you are using a string for the first name and a char array for the second?

Comment: @ArtemSolovev Sure that's informative, your question is train wrecked though.

Comment: @dingalapadum I'm doing based on the conditions of the problem in the book.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ You're in programming with about 30 years of experience years old but I study programming for about a month. Pimp my communication skills.

Comment: @ArtemSolovev Hmm... Could we stay zen and friendly here? Replace `strcat` with `strcpy` and you're ok.

Comment: @Daniel Strul I made a stupid mistake. Thank you for your time and help)

Comment: @ArtemSolovev _"Pimp my communication skills."_ Pimp them yourself, I probably can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the second constructor m_cFname[0] is not initialized with 0
use strcpy instead of strcat

and you will have problem with longer first names

Comment: I mixed up the function names. Stupid mistake. Thank you for help